# ColorAnimation с использованием DynamicResource

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация, style, storyboard

Хочу сделать плавную анимацию кнопки при наезде на нее мышкой. Мне нужно сделать это в стиле кнопки

Самый подходящий вариант - использовать ColorAnimation

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                                To="{DynamicResource WhiteColor}"
                                Duration="0:0:0.3"></ColorAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Естественно, сделать это не получается, так как нельзя использовать DynamicResource. Однако, мне нужно именно так, по причине использования стилей оформления для окон.

Ни за что не поверю, что никто не сталкивался с подобной проблемой и не решил ее

Comment: Надо с помощью Attached Property делать, наверное

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как и предположили в комментариях - нужно делать через attached properties. Так и сделал. Выглядит немного костыльно, но работает как я и хотел

```
namespace ModPlusStyle.Controls.Helpers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

    public class ButtonAssist
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<Button, Color> _initBackgroundBrush = new Dictionary<Button, Color>();

        private static readonly Dictionary<Button, Color> _initForegroundBrush = new Dictionary<Button, Color>();

        private static readonly Dictionary<Button, Color> _initBorderBrush = new Dictionary<Button, Color>();

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimateMouseOverProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AnimateMouseOver",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(ButtonAssist),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, AnimateMouseOverChangedCallback));

        public static void SetAnimateMouseOver(DependencyObject element, bool value)
        {
            element.SetValue(AnimateMouseOverProperty, value);
        }

        public static bool GetAnimateMouseOver(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (bool)element.GetValue(AnimateMouseOverProperty);
        }

        private static void AnimateMouseOverChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is Button button)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    button.MouseEnter += ButtonOnMouseEnter;
                    button.MouseLeave += ButtonOnMouseLeave;
                }
                else
                {
                    button.MouseEnter -= ButtonOnMouseEnter;
                    button.MouseLeave -= ButtonOnMouseLeave;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ButtonOnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Button button &&
                !(button.Parent is WindowCommands) &&
                button.Background is SolidColorBrush backgroundSolidColorBrush &&
                button.Foreground is SolidColorBrush foregroundSolidColorBrush &&
                button.BorderBrush is SolidColorBrush bordersSolidColorBrush)
            {
                var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(button);
                if (parentWindow != null)
                {
                    if (parentWindow.Resources["WhiteBrush"] is SolidColorBrush whiteBrush &&
                        parentWindow.Resources["BlackBrush"] is SolidColorBrush blackBrush &&
                        parentWindow.Resources["AccentColorBrush"] is SolidColorBrush accentColorBrush)
                    {
                        if (_initBackgroundBrush.ContainsKey(button))
                            _initBackgroundBrush[button] = backgroundSolidColorBrush.Color;
                        else
                            _initBackgroundBrush.Add(button, backgroundSolidColorBrush.Color);

                        if (_initForegroundBrush.ContainsKey(button))
                            _initForegroundBrush[button] = foregroundSolidColorBrush.Color;
                        else
                            _initForegroundBrush.Add(button, foregroundSolidColorBrush.Color);

                        if (_initBorderBrush.ContainsKey(button))
                            _initBorderBrush[button] = bordersSolidColorBrush.Color;
                        else
                            _initBorderBrush.Add(button, bordersSolidColorBrush.Color);

                        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(backgroundSolidColorBrush.Color);
                        ColorAnimation backgroundColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation(
                            backgroundSolidColorBrush.Color,
                            whiteBrush.Color,
                            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
                        button.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, backgroundColorAnimation);

                        button.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(foregroundSolidColorBrush.Color);
                        ColorAnimation foregroundColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation(
                            foregroundSolidColorBrush.Color,
                            blackBrush.Color,
                            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
                        button.Foreground.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, foregroundColorAnimation);

                        button.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(bordersSolidColorBrush.Color);
                        ColorAnimation borderBrushColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation(
                            backgroundSolidColorBrush.Color,
                            accentColorBrush.Color,
                            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
                        button.BorderBrush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, borderBrushColorAnimation);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ButtonOnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is Button button &&
                !(button.Parent is WindowCommands) &&
                _initBackgroundBrush.ContainsKey(button) &&
                _initForegroundBrush.ContainsKey(button))
            {
                var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(button);
                if (parentWindow != null)
                {
                    if (parentWindow.Resources["AccentColorBrush"] is SolidColorBrush accentColorBrush &&
                        parentWindow.Resources["ForegroundForAccentedBrush"] is SolidColorBrush foregroundForAccentedBrush)
                    {
                        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(((SolidColorBrush)button.Background).Color);
                        ColorAnimation backgroundColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation(
                            ((SolidColorBrush)button.Background).Color,
                            _initBackgroundBrush[button],
                            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
                        backgroundColorAnimation.Completed += (o, args) =>
                        {
                            if (!_initBackgroundBrush.ContainsKey(button) ||
                                (_initBackgroundBrush.ContainsKey(button) && _initBackgroundBrush[button] == accentColorBrush.Color))
                                button.SetResourceReference(Control.BackgroundProperty, "AccentColorBrush");
                            _initBackgroundBrush.Remove(button);
                        };
                        button.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, backgroundColorAnimation);

                        button.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(((SolidColorBrush)button.Foreground).Color);
                        ColorAnimation foregroundColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation(
                            ((SolidColorBrush)button.Foreground).Color,
                            _initForegroundBrush[button],
                            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
                        foregroundColorAnimation.Completed += (o, args) =>
                        {
                            if (!_initForegroundBrush.ContainsKey(button) ||
                                (_initForegroundBrush.ContainsKey(button) && _initForegroundBrush[button] == foregroundForAccentedBrush.Color))
                                button.SetResourceReference(Control.ForegroundProperty, "ForegroundForAccentedBrush");
                            _initForegroundBrush.Remove(button);
                        };
                        button.Foreground.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, foregroundColorAnimation);

                        button.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(((SolidColorBrush)button.BorderBrush).Color);
                        ColorAnimation borderColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation(
                            ((SolidColorBrush)button.Background).Color,
                            _initBorderBrush[button],
                            new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
                        backgroundColorAnimation.Completed += (o, args) =>
                        {
                            if (!_initBorderBrush.ContainsKey(button) ||
                                (_initBorderBrush.ContainsKey(button) && _initBorderBrush[button] == accentColorBrush.Color))
                                button.SetResourceReference(Control.BorderBrushProperty, "AccentColorBrush");
                            _initBorderBrush.Remove(button);
                        };
                        button.BorderBrush.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, borderColorAnimation);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```